# Why are rms values used to calculate power in amplifiers?

Tags: amplifier, circuit-design

I am taking a beginning EE course, and it seems like we just use the given peak voltages to find the current and voltage gains of an amplifier. When it comes to finding the power from its source and the power deliver to its load however, we have to use the Vrms and Irms. Why is this necessary to do, instead of just using the peak of a sinusoidal voltage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Back in the stony ages, before AC, the power into a load was simply the voltage across the load times the current through it, so if an incandescent lamp with 120 volts across it had a current of 1 ampere through it, the heat and light it was generating were equal to what it was receiving from the generator: 120 watts.

Then, when sinusoidal AC came along, with all of its peaks and valleys, 120 volt peaks were no longer able to drive the lamps to full power, but a sine wave with 170 volt peaks could.

I don't know the genealogy of it, but someone in the mix back then discovered that if one makes a sine table with, say, one degree increments in X and puts 170 volts at 90 degrees, if one took a "sample" by calculating the voltage at every degree and squaring it, added up all the samples, divided that sum by the number of samples taken, and then took the square root of that sum, that Root Mean Square value would cause heating in the load exactly equal to that in the DC case.

Answer (score 2):

Using the peak voltage and current will give you the peak power, which will only apply for that instant.

Using RMS voltage and current will give you the average power over a whole cycle of the AC signal.

Comment: You have the right idea, but your statement is, well, not right. It is perfectly possible to compute the average (or mean) power of an amplifier's output, and it's not the same as RMS. In fact, it's a bit lower.

Comment: 'Peak power' doesn't exist; the term was invented by manufacturers to make their amplifiers appear more powerful than they actually are. 'Power' is Based on RMS values.

Comment: @Chu .Gezundheit! Funny, but while your premise is valid, your conclusion  isn't necessarily true. Consider a RADAR set transmitting a 100kW pulse.

Comment: @Chu Of course peak power exists.  It's the peak of the instantaneous power waveform.  https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Peak-power-average-power-tau-T.png

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast SimonB is correct.  \$V_\mathrm{RMS} \cdot I_\mathrm{RMS} = P_\mathrm{avg}\$.  It's possible to compute actual "RMS power" from the power waveform, instead of "average power", but "RMS power" is not a useful quantity.  In audio, when people say "RMS power" they are mistaken, and really mean "average power" (which is calculated from RMS voltage).

Comment: @endolith, I can't find a scientific definition of peak power as applied to an audio amplifier.

Comment: @endolith: And of course, that is a dot product between phasors, not mere multiplication.  (The equation using ordinary multiplication includes a term for "power factor" which is equal to "cosine of angle between phasors" that arises in dot product)

Comment: @Chu It's just the maximum instantaneous output power.  It would be 2 times the average power for a sine wave, for instance.  While for a square wave, peak power and average power are equal.

Comment: @BenVoigt That formula is for resistive loads, so it's just plain multiplication.  RMS voltage is a scalar, not a phasor.  For reactive loads you need to know the angle, not just the RMS value.

Comment: @endolith: Well, sort of.  The RMS operation yields a scalar.  But (RMS voltage and phase) is just as good a way of describing a phasor sinusoidal voltage as (peak voltage and phase), and if you use the former phasor, it works as a phasor dot product for complex loads.

Answer (score 1):

Gain calculations don't have to rely on the signal being a sinwaves because, if the amplifier is linear you can use any part of the input waveform as the input reference providing you use the corresponding point on the output waveform.

There are some limitations but it is generally correct. When referring to power outputs a lot of smoke blowing happens and you get the less reputable suppliers talking about things like "peak stereo music power" usually mentioned somewhere in the small print and, of course, this exaggerates how good an amp is.

The correct way is to use sinwaves and this is usually called (if a little misleading) RMS output power.

This is proper watts just like your electricity meter measures. So, if instead you used the peak of the sinwave, the power in watts would be exaggerated by 2 and you fall on the side of the smoke blowing marketing riff-raff that plague the industry.

Comment: RMS voltage times RMS current is *average* power, not RMS power.  "Average power" is the correct spec.  If you wrote the actual "RMS power" of the power waveform, you'd be inflating your specs relative to the true average power.

Comment: @endolith, if the voltage and current are across and through a reactance then the product is certainly not power of any flavour.

Comment: @Chu Yes, in audio we assume a resistive load, which is not really accurate.

Comment: @endolith I'm afraid I have to agree with you completely but the audio "crowd" do tend to use this term and I did say it was misleading. If you've ever read my answers on AC power calcs you wouldn't doubt my sincerity or accuracy.

Comment: @endolith RMS voltage times RMS current is _apparent_ power (which is measured in VA as opposed to real power measured in W).  The distinction sounds academical but real power is what is converted into heat and sound.  Apparent power is to a good degree what stresses the amp (actually, typical transistor power amps are stressed more by reactive power than real power due to the manner the power transistors feed from the "power rails").  "RMS power" is not a real thing because there is no point in squaring a momentary power: you just average it.

Comment: @user107063 That's not relevant to my comment, which is about "RMS power" (RMS of the power waveform) vs "average power" (time average of the power waveform).  If you have a resistive load, apparent power and real power are the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You have answered your question already yourself. You just have to do the calculations.

If you take a sine voltage with 1V peak and a (purely ohmic for the simplicity of the calculaiton) load of 1Ω, you get a current with 1A peak. Then of course you could claim, the power delivered is 1W. But this is true only for an infinitesimal short period of time. Most of the time the voltage and consequently the amperage and power are much less. So if you add up all the energy pumped into the load over a period and divide that energy by the duration of the period, you get a realistic power. Guess what: This value is equal to your RMS calculation.

For an ohmic load the momentanous power is \$P={u²(t)/R}\$.
so if you set \$u(t)=sin(t)\$ you can calculate the momentanous power to

\$1/2R * (1-cos(2t))\$

The peak power is only equal to RMS for a constant DC signal or a bipolar rectangular wave. You must admit, those signals are very rare and usually don't make sense being amplified.

Furthermore: Imagine a rectangular singnal with a very low duty cycle. Something like 1 ms short pulses with 1 V amplitude every second. The peak power would calculate to 1 W, while the average power is three orders of magnitude smaller! You might be mighty surprised, that your little resistor as a load can stay so cool.